# How to open html by browser inside Linux shell

Tags: command-line

I have remote Ubuntu server where I deployed django project and set it (project) up by logging system. I can access server only by shell. Each log record of project save in directory like HTML file.  Opening and researching log records using vim isn't convinient for me because of it I want to open these files by browser.  Can I pass command to server to open file by my device browser.

Comment: `lynx`, `w3m` and other text browser available.   `lynx` itself is very old, being first released in 1992, but still really useful!

Comment: @guiverc but I want to open it in GUI browser like Chrome etc

Comment: If you are using SSH access, I would mount that directory via `sshfs` (or via Nautilus) and will browse the files with the local resources - GUI environment, etc.